# Line break to C location address

Tags: overleaf

I am writing a report in which I report some recurring error tracebacks. I made a template to indicate the traceback, but I would like to break the line from the location hyperlink. What would be the command to do these line breaks?

```
File "/home/awgomes/SALOME-9.6.0-UB18.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB18.04/GEOM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salome/salome/geom/geomBuilder.py"
```

My text:
[image: PDF picture]

````
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{style/Refrep}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

% Hyperref things for pdf and html:
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Codes}
\definecolor{DOrange}{rgb}{1,.4,.2}
\usepackage{layout}


\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black,topline=true,bottomline=true,leftline=false,rightline=false, 
backgroundcolor=wikkiCinzaCode]
\begin{minted}[linenos=false,numbersep=11pt,framesep=2mm,fontsize=\footnotesize,obeytabs=true,tabsize=2]{cpp}

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/awgomes/winds_core/tutorials/geo_auto/Teste1/pa/generateBlade.py", 
line 304, in <module>
 pa1.CreateCAD()
File "/home/awgomes/winds_core/tutorials/geo_auto/Teste1/pa/generateBlade.py", 
line 128, in CreateCAD
 Solid_inteiro = geompy.MakeSolid(Fuse_1)
File "/home/awgomes/SALOME-9.6.0-UB18.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB18.04/GEOM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salome/salome/geom/geomBuilder.py",
line 364, in OpenCallClose
 res = theFunction(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/awgomes/SALOME-9.6.0-UB18.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB18.04/GEOM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salome/salome/geom/geomBuilder.py",
line 4960, in MakeSolid
 raise RuntimeError("MakeSolidShells : Unable to create solid from unclosed shape")
RuntimeError: MakeSolidShells : Unable to create solid from unclosed shape
ERROR:salomeContext:SystemExit 1 in method _runAppli.

\end{minted}
\end{mdframed}
\vspace{0.3cm}```
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you also include the minimally required documentclass and packages, so that we can copy and paste your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow minted to break lines with the `breaklines` key and then allow it to break your very long paths at the `/` by using `breakafter=/`

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

% Hyperref things for pdf and html:
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Codes}
\definecolor{DOrange}{rgb}{1,.4,.2}
\usepackage{layout}


\begin{document}

\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black,topline=true,bottomline=true,leftline=false,rightline=false, 
backgroundcolor=lightgray]
\begin{minted}[linenos=false,numbersep=11pt,framesep=2mm,fontsize=\footnotesize,obeytabs=true,tabsize=2,breaklines,breakafter=/]{cpp}

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/awgomes/winds_core/tutorials/geo_auto/Teste1/pa/generateBlade.py", 
line 304, in <module>
 pa1.CreateCAD()
File "/home/awgomes/winds_core/tutorials/geo_auto/Teste1/pa/generateBlade.py", 
line 128, in CreateCAD
 Solid_inteiro = geompy.MakeSolid(Fuse_1)
File "/home/awgomes/SALOME-9.6.0-UB18.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB18.04/GEOM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salome/salome/geom/geomBuilder.py",
line 364, in OpenCallClose
 res = theFunction(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/awgomes/SALOME-9.6.0-UB18.04-SRC/BINARIES-UB18.04/GEOM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salome/salome/geom/geomBuilder.py",
line 4960, in MakeSolid
 raise RuntimeError("MakeSolidShells : Unable to create solid from unclosed shape")
RuntimeError: MakeSolidShells : Unable to create solid from unclosed shape
ERROR:salomeContext:SystemExit 1 in method _runAppli.

\end{minted}
\end{mdframed}
\vspace{0.3cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]